# take out specific columns from mulitple files

Tags: awk

I have multiple files that look like the one below. They are tab-separated. For all the files I would like to take out **column 1** and the column that start with **XF:Z:**. This will give me **output 1**
The files names are **htseqoutput*.sam.sam** where * varies. I am not sure about the awk function use, and if the for-loop is correct.

```
for f in htseqoutput*.sam.sam
do
awk ????? "$f" > “out${f#htseqoutput}”
done
```

input example

```
AACAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGGAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTC_11  16  chr22   39715068    24  51M *   0   0   GACAATCAGCACACAGTTCCTGTCCGCCCGTCAATAAGTTCATCATCTGTT IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII AS:i:-12    XN:i:0  XM:i:2  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:2  MD:Z:18T31G0    YT:Z:UU XF:Z:SNORD43
GTTTCCTTAGTGTAGCGGTTATCACATTCGCCT_0 16  chr19   4724687 40  33M *   0   0   AGGCGAATGTGATAACCGCTACACTAAGGAAAC   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:26C6   YT:Z:UU XF:Z:tRNA
TCGACTCCCGGTGTGGGAACC_0 16  chr13   45492060    23  21M *   0   0   GGTTCCCACACCGGGAGTCGA   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:0C20   YT:Z:UU XF:Z:tRNA
```

output 1:

```
AACAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGGAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTC_11   SNORD43
GTTTCCTTAGTGTAGCGGTTATCACATTCGCCT_0 tRNA
TCGACTCCCGGTGTGGGAACC_0 tRNA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try, if column with "XF:Z:" is always at the end

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}{n=split($NF,a,":"); print $1, a[n]}' file.sam
```

you get,

```
AACAGATGATGAACTTATTGACGGGCGGACAGGAACTGTGTGCTGATTGTC_11  SNORD43
GTTTCCTTAGTGTAGCGGTTATCACATTCGCCT_0 tRNA
TCGACTCCCGGTGTGGGAACC_0 tRNA
```

or, if this column is a variable position for each file

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
     FNR==1{
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
         if($i ~ /^XF:Z:/) break
       }
     }
     {n=split($i,a,":"); print $1, a[n]}' file.sam
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you could just use sed for this:

```
sed -r 's/^([ACGT0-9_]+).*XF:Z:([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1\t\2/' file
```

This captures the part at the start of the line and the alphanumeric part following `XF:Z:` and outputs them, separated by a tab character. One potential advantage of this approach is that it will work independently of the position of the `XF:Z:` string.

Your loop looks OK (you can use this sed command in place of the awk part) but be careful with your quotes. `"` should be used, not `“`/`”`.

Alternatively, if you prefer awk (and assuming that the bit you're interested in is always part of the last field), you can use a custom field separator:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]](XF:Z:)?' -v OFS='\t' '{print $1, $NF}' file
```

This optionally adds the `XF:Z:` part to the field separator, so that it is removed from the start of the last field.

Comment: Thanks! Could you check if the for-loop is OK? It seem to get stuck in the terminal somehow.

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with it, other than the quotes. Perhaps you're missing a close quote around your awk command or something? It's hard to say.

Comment: sed: illegal option -- r
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

Comment: When running:   for f in htseqoutput*.sam.sam
do
sed -r 's/^([ACGT0-9_]+).*XF:Z:([[:alnum:]]+).*/\1\t\2/' "$f" > "Rfam_Counts_combined${f#IsomiR}"
done

Comment: Looks like you're on a mac, which means that extended regex mode is enabled with `-E` instead of `-r`.

Comment: Thanks. Your awk function worked, however, the sed did not. probably due to different formating of my inputs.

Comment: Without seeing any more of your input (a line that doesn't work would be interesting), I'm not sure why that would be the case.